# M/G/1 queueing problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I need to prove that in the M/G/1 queueing system with Poisson arrivals with parameter lambda and exponential service time with parameter mu, that q_k = (lambda/(lambda+mu))^k (mu/(lambda+mu)).

Comment: You don't specify what $q_k$ is. I guess you are referring to the stationary distribution of the queue size for $M/M/1$ (not correct for $G$ service).  You need to define the appropriate birth and death process and solve the balance equations.